# Field is never assigned to, and will always have its default value / Unity /

Tags: javascript, c++, unity-game-engine

I just started to learn Unity and I got stuck on this error.

The code is working.   I tagged FPS Controller to Player.

I did exactly same things as the guy on tutorial did.  anyone knows how to solve this problem ?

[image]

```
        #pragma strict

        var ourDoor : Transform;
        private var drawGUI = false;
        private var doorClosed = true;

        function Update () 
        {
            if(drawGUI == true && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
            {
                changeDoorState();
            }
        }

        function OnTriggerEnter(theCollider : Collider)
        {
            if(theCollider.tag == "Player")
            {
                drawGUI = true;
            }
        }

        function OnTriggerExit(theCollider : Collider)
        {
            if(theCollider.tag == "Player")
            {
                drawGUI = false;
            }
        }

        function OnGUI() 
        {
            if(drawGUI == true)
            {
                GUI.Box(Rect (Screen.width*0.5-51, 200, 102, 22,) "Press E To Open");
            }
        }

        function changeDoorState()
        {
            if(doorClosed == true)
            {
                ourDoor.GetComponent.<Animation>().CrossFade("doorOpen");
                ourDoor.GetComponent.<AudioSource>().Play();
                doorClosed = false;
                yield WaitForSeconds(5);
                ourDoor.GetComponent.<Animation>().CrossFade("doorClose");
                ourDoor.GetComponent.<AudioSource>().Play();
                doorClosed = true;

            }
        }
```

Comment: They're just warnings, not errors. In this case there should be nothing keeping you from simply ignoring them.

Comment: It seems to me, that you have to assign some values in the inspector. Click the Player object, and look under the script component. Is there any 0 values there? But, as BHS said, if it works either way, you can simply ignore the messages.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the inspector of the Player Game Object.
Under the script object, you can assign values to variables in the inspector.

http://prntscr.com/dnp3n8

Look at the screenshot.
If the values are like these, you might have to set them to some sort of value, to get stuff moving :)